# SQL Use CASE in where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

Here is an example of table:

```
     acIdent   |  acSubject          | acCode
     200.2.013 |                     | F-202
     200.2.013 | Minsk traktor works | F202.GRS
```

This is what i tried to do:

```
     declare @subj varchar(30)

     set @subj = 'Minsk traktor works'

     select acIdent, acSubject, acCode
     from tHE_SetItemExtItemSubj where acIdent = '200.2.013' and
     acSubject = (
            case 
            when @subj = acSubject then @subj
            else '' end
         )
```

My goal is to get only one record. My example returns both records.
When @subj exists in table then return acCode - F202.GRS, else return F-202.

Help pls

Comment: I don't understand your logic. If `@subj = acSubject` then `acSubject = @subj` (they are the same expression reversed). Is your not logic simply `WHERE acSubject  IN (subj,'')`?

Comment: Could you perhaps provide more sample data and your expected results? 1 example often doesn't help portray a full requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
 declare @subj varchar(30)

 set @subj = 'Minsk traktor works'

 select top(1) acIdent, acSubject, acCode
 from tHE_SetItemExtItemSubj 
 where acIdent = '200.2.013' 
   and (acSubject = @subj or acSubject = '')
 order by len(acSubject) desc
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i was looking for.
But is it possible to get the same result from using CASE?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I've compiled your query above like below:

```
declare @MyTable as table
    (   ID  int identity primary key
    ,   acIdent     varchar(100)
    ,   acSubject   varchar(200)
    ,   acCode      varchar(100)
    )

insert into @MyTable
    (   acIdent
    ,   acSubject
    ,   acCode  )
    values
    (   '200.2.013'
    ,   ''
    ,   'F-202' ),
    (   '200.2.013'
    ,   'Minsk traktor works'
    ,   'F-202' )

declare @subj varchar(30)

    set @subj = 'Minsk traktor works'

    select
        acIdent
    ,   acSubject
    ,   acCode
    ,   case acSubject when  @subj then @subj else '' end
    from @MyTable where acIdent = '200.2.013'
    and  acSubject = (case when acSubject = @subj then @subj else '' end)

    select
        acIdent
    ,   acSubject
    ,   acCode
    ,   case acSubject when  @subj then @subj else '' end
    from @MyTable where acIdent = '200.2.013'
    and  acSubject = @subj
```

From the 2 queries, you will notice that the first query will always provide you with 2 rows as your code is flawed.

The second query you will notice will give you only one record.

The results will look like this:

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sZDA.png)

Comment: You are right, and I understand why I am getting two results.
Your example works only when acSubject is 'Minsk traktor works' or ' '
If 'Minsk traktor works' does not exist in table, acSubject should be  ' ', and return acCode - F-202
HoneyBadger resolved my issue, but still I wonder if this could be done by CASE.

Answer (score 1):

Won't this be helpful as you have to get only one record using one condition only. Why use case if you have to check against only single condition?

```
declare @subj varchar(30)
set @subj = 'Minsk traktor works'
select top(1) acIdent, acSubject, acCode
from tHE_SetItemExtItemSubj 
where acIdent = '200.2.013' 
and (acSubject = @subj)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do something like this with case functions:

```
 -- assumes @subj is not '' nor null. 
 select y.acIdent, y.acSubject, y.acCode
 from tHE_SetItemExtItemSubj y
 where y.acIdent = '200.2.013' 
   and y.acSubject = 
   (case 
    when exists(select * from  tHE_SetItemExtItemSubj x where 
                x.acIdent = y.acIdent and x.acSubject = @subj) 
    then @subj else '' 
    end)
```

Case functions can also be nested. Here's an example which has the same functionality as the above (it is probably overkill in this case, but the technique can be useful when you are doing more complex things):

```
 -- assumes @subj is not '' nor null. 
 select y.acIdent, y.acSubject, y.acCode
 from tHE_SetItemExtItemSubj y
 where y.acIdent = '200.2.013' 
   and 1 = 
   (case 
    when exists(select * from  tHE_SetItemExtItemSubj x where 
                x.acIdent = y.acIdent and x.acSubject = @subj) 
    then 
        case when y.acSubject = @subj then 1 else 0 end
    else 
        case when y.acSubject = '' then 1 else 0 end
    end)
```